# how to add multiple listview in scrollview

Tags: android

how to ad multiple listview in scroll view ihave code which suppport single listview which is scrolling how do i add multiple listview? below is my code which support scroll single listview how do i add multiple listview???

```
              public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisview);
    View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        list.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }


              <!--activity_main.xml--->



                  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res 
       /android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dip">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="30sp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/lisview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
          </LinearLayout>


            <!-----header.xnml---->


                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header View" 
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

      </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: ListView has its own scrollable functionality... No need to add it to scrollview.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why do you need multiple `ListView`-s?

Comment: bcoz my screen look like this    http://imgur.com/kR6vlKX

Comment: Have you considered using `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: For that you have to use Expandable ListView Or you can take independent ListView in your xml file....

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand... How can the user choose if he scrolls the scrollview or the listView?  It is generally not a good idea to put a listView in a ScrollView.
But, just put another ListView Under the first one in your xml layout.

Comment: no in my code which i paste above listvirew not scroll only page is scroll

Comment: I don't believe that in the link that you attached It's LisvtViews. I think it's a simple 3 vertical linear layouts.

Comment: but is load  in listvew

Comment: I am sorry, I can't understand you english, can you try again?

Comment: imean i load data inlistviewhow do i change listview to another object? is there any other toools which display same likelistview??

Comment: no, You can try and add three listViews with fixed size instead or wrap_content

Comment: but what about if phone have diffrent size whren run application isbigger or smaller???

Answer (score 0):

It is quiet old UX problem - list view inside list view. It is not allowed in Android, but you can try some alternatives - **one list view with different type of items**.

Android list view & adapter support ViewType elements, so you can easily implemented it. For example,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this));
}

private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;   //any number what you need.
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //view type is managed as zero-based index.
        if(position > 5)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if( convertView == null ){
            // View Recycling is managed separately based on its view type,
            // so you don't need to worry about view corruptions.

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            int type = getItemViewType(position);
            switch (type){
                case 0:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_type_0);
                case 1:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_type_1);
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}//end of inner class 
}//end of class
```

You can use multiple view type in order to implement some special dividers or section bars, too.

Comment: What I mean is instead of adding another listview, you can add another type of item for one list view by overriding getViewTypeCount & getItemViewType methods inside your adapter. The example what I showed is using 2 different type of item in one adapter, it means you can two different type of child view in your one listview.

Comment: You may refer this blog post for more detailed code example. - [handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/)